# How to get the last send message value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these items in a list named as **calls**

- UPDATE BTST CALL: BUY WELSPUN CORP (BSE CODE 532144) AT 145.75 FOR
  TARGET Of 156, STOP LOSS 141.
- Positional Technical Call Target Achieved in JSLHISAR at 185, Call
  initiated at 169.
- Intraday Technical call Buy ASTRAMICRO Above 119 with SL 114 Target
- Intraday Technical call Buy ASTRAMICRO Above 119 with SL 114 Target
- BUY ACC CASH AT 1908-1911, STOP LOSS 1894, TARGET 1932-1942.

this list will get updated like this as you can see 2 new items are added at top

- Positional Technical Call Buy FINPIPE above 157.6 with SL 151 Target
- 1-2 DAYS Technical Call Buy TIMETECHNO above 79.2 with SL 77 Target
  84.
- UPDATE BTST CALL: BUY WELSPUN CORP (BSE CODE 532144) AT 145.75 FOR
  TARGET Of 156, STOP LOSS 141.
- Positional Technical Call Target Achieved in JSLHISAR at 185, Call
  initiated at 169.
- Intraday Technical call Buy ASTRAMICRO Above 119 with SL 114 Target
- Intraday Technical call Buy ASTRAMICRO Above 119 with SL 114 Target

these all list items will be send on telegram. I want to store the value of last item send on telegram so that when it run again it will send items above the last item send.

I have written this code:

```
    last_call_message= "UPDATE BTST CALL: BUY WELSPUN CORP (BSE CODE 532144) AT 145.75 FOR TARGET Of 156, STOP LOSS 141."
#I have declared this variable my self to test the code.
    for item in calls:
        if(item == last_call_message):
            last_call_index = int(calls.index(item))
    for item in range(last_call_index):
        bot_url= 'https://api.telegram.org/bot74522:wqA5vE6vTOKYoM0/sendMessage?chat_id=-578114&text={}'.format(calls[item])
        requests.get(bot_url)
```

while running this it was working as I want it it has send the 2 items updated in list.
but In this I have declared what last message was send I want to update it automatically what last message was send.

Comment: this code will be running 24*7 and items in list will get updated automatically